# VOIP feature with twilio SDK?

Tags: twilio, ios10, voip, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I had implemented twilio calling features one of my ios application, VOIP is not working while the incoming call. Is any one of my friend wast implemented the twilio calling funtionality with VOIP?

Comment: Please clarify your question and include some code which SO can help with. Thank you!

Comment: Hi - I have implement the push kit for receiving the incoming VOIP notification via Twilio, i am following all the steps which are in the [link] (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/ios/getting-started#setup-your-apple-voip-service) , didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload not called when i receive incoming call from other user.